# Fetching all the images from url

Tags: php, image, testing, web

Today I am testing a site. in that site i found some images are in sequence
for eg.

```
http://www.example.com/PHOTO/P323423.gif
http://www.example.com/PHOTO/P323424.gif
http://www.example.com/PHOTO/P323425.gif
http://www.example.com/PHOTO/P323426.gif
```

...

Now I want to fetch/download all these images for later use.

is there any way to download all these or see in one page.

I have tried this link also

```
http://www.example.com/PHOTO/
```

Then i got an error - 
You are not authorized to view this page.

Pls suggest how can i able to view all the images in one page. 
The site coded in php.
Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example link ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your source urls follow a numbered, linear progression (e.g. -3423.gif to -3424.gif to -3425.gif). Have you thought about using php and its curl library? A sample approach would be:

```
1) Establish the bounds of your scrape (gif xxx - xyz)

2) Write a curl request loop that increments consistently in this range and gets the result

3) Refine the curl return and posit the info somewhere (local file i/o or database are two easy ways)
```

Here is a great post on general curl usage on stack:
[PHP cURL GET request and request's body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230246/php-curl-get-request-and-requests-body)

Furthermore, trying access the dir of `PHOTO` (or it may be a software route depending on the app) will probably entail different permissions rather than just trying to view a gif inside the dir. Is this your site? Be aware, not all admins take kindly to url scraping (what you would be doing) its best to try and get in contact with the admin for a dump or clearance in the first place to scrape their server and bog-down their traffic.

Tell me what you think

Cheers!