# How to detect if a re-Captcha site key is valid via javascript?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm attempting to detect the 'Invalid site key' error for googles re-Captcha via javascript so the error can be reported to the server for further handling. I'm using the explicit rendering mode and calling the api function `grecaptcha.render('iframeid', {'site-key':'xxx'});`although this function doesn't return any error response or throw an exception even if it loads the following: [image]

I can't simply read the loaded error text either as it's loaded in an iframe on a different domain. Is there anyway to detect an invalid site key automatically, either via javascript or server side?

**Edit**
Final solution was to load a test page with phantomjs and parse the html of the recaptcha

Comment: why do you need `to detect the 'Invalid site key'`? Can't you do it at google recaptcha admin page?

Comment: Its a common mistake to forget to update the allowable domains in the dashboard when pushing a new site live. We want to be able to automatically detect when the recaptcha is failing and have emails automatically sent to devs so it can be fixed. More specifically we're looking for the Invalid domain error, although any error of the recaptcha should be detected.

Comment: contact me personally for further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not provide methods to verify *site key*, neither you can hack/access reCaptcha html code by JS since the reCapthca is in an iframe and frame's code is not programmatically accessible client-side.

> Its a common mistake to forget to update the allowable domains in the dashboard when pushing a new site live.

Since you manage multiple domains I'd recommend you to use one *site key* for all of the domains you use. Use [secure token](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token) for that.

### Hack

Another option might be that you develop a script that will visit site(s) of interest, make screenshot/snap of loaded reCaptcha, apply OCR (eg. using [this](https://webscraping.pro/uipath-robotic-process-automation-software/)) and return a result if *site key* is valid or not.

Answer (score 2):

As Google does not provide an official way to check this, I've just implemented a workaround performing a `GET` request on Google's Recaptcha URL. I've made using PHP, but it's not hard to adapt the solution for JavaScript, although it can end on a Cross-Origin error due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So if someone tests this solution using JavaScript, let us know how it goes (and if it does not work, it's always possible to run an AJAX to your own server and check the validity directly from your server).

Besides that, in my case, I'm using Invisible ReCaptcha v2, but I think this approach can be used for other Recaptchas as well.

1. First, you should mount your URL. I couldn't find a way to determine this "co" param, and I don't know what it means. But it looks like different values are all accepted on different sites. You can look for this value by adding the Recaptcha code on your page (no matter if it's with valid keys or not) and then checking the `src` param on the generated `<iframe>`.

```php
        $recaptcha_url = sprintf(
            'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=%s&co=%s&hl=%s&size=%s',
            RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY,
            '<co_param_value>',
            'en-US',
            'invisible'
        );
```

on JavaScript it would be something like this:

```js
    recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=' + RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY + ' &co=' + CO_VALUE + '&hl=en-US&size=invisible';
```

If you are not using Invisible Recaptcha, the `size` param must be different. But you can also omit it because, at least in my testing, it was not necessary for checking if the Site Key is valid (the same for the language param `hl`).

2. Then, you perform a GET request on this URL. On PHP, you can use [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230246/php-curl-get-request-and-requests-body). If it's Wordpress, you can use [`wp_remote_get`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/). On JavaScript (jQuery, actually), you can use `$.get`.

```
    $.get( recaptcha_url, function(data, status){ ... });
```

3. Finally, you check if the response body has the string `'Recaptcha.anchor.ErrorMain.init'`. This means when the Recaptcha Site Key is not valid for the current domain, Google processes the error, and this string appears on the response body (actually, any ReCaptcha error would result on this string, so remember this is a workaround).

If you are using Wordpress, you can do it with [`wp_remote_retrieve_body`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_retrieve_body/). Something like this:

```php
    $response      = wp_remote_get( $recaptcha_url );
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

    if( strpos( $response_body, 'recaptcha.anchor.ErrorMain.init' ) !== false ) {
        // Site is not valid for current Recaptcha Keys
    }
```

On JavaScript, I think you can check the `data` variable received on `$.get`.

Unfortunately, this is not a strong solution. Google can change both the request and the response, and this could break the implementation. But there is nothing we can do about it as there isn't an official call to check the keys.

Comment: great answer. But from where you are getting this url             'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=%s&co=%s&hl=%s&size=%s',
Please send the documentation link of corresponding url

Comment: For anyone wondering, the `co` parameter corresponds to the current host URL encoded in base64. reCAPTCHA uses this to check against allowed domain.