# How to send GET request with php curl

Tags: php, curl, get-request

I have a problem when I want to send a GET request with php curl or file_get_contents function !!!
I think this problem is for my URL !!!
please help me ...
my code (file_get_contents function):

```
$SMStext = "text";
$SMSmobile = 'phonenumber';
$SMSurl = "http://api.payamak-panel.com/post/sendsms.ashx?username=username&password=pass&from=smsnumber&to=";
$SMSurl .= $SMSmobile;
$SMSurl .= '&text=';
$SMSurl .= $SMStext;

echo file_get_contents($SMSurl);
```

my code (php curl):

```
$SMStext = "text";
$SMSmobile = 'phonenumber';
$SMSurl = "http://api.payamak-panel.com/post/sendsms.ashx?username=username&password=pass&from=smsnumber&to=";
$SMSurl .= $SMSmobile;
$SMSurl .= '&text=';
$SMSurl .= $SMStext;
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$SMSurl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $output
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL GET request and request's body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230246/php-curl-get-request-and-requests-body)

Answer (score 0):

This URL redirects to another URL.
You need to add: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`